# How can I with css position the elements like the image?

Tags: html, css, text-align

I have two selectors to play with to achieve this design:

[image]

I have tried almost everything but I just cant seem to get the text to float right next to the big letters

Here is the code:

[Jsbin](http://jsbin.com/UHiZUJU/1/edit)

html:

```
<div class="processlinks-section-template">
<div class="processlinks-section-item" data-letter="H">
    <div class="processlinks-section-item-title">
       <a href="http://aftonbladet.se">Haftonbladet.se</a>
    </div>
    <div class="processlinks-section-item-title">
        <a href="http://teabagz.com">Hteabagz.com</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="processlinks-section-item" data-letter="C">
    <div class="processlinks-section-item-title">
       <a href="http://Cftonbladet.se">Cftonbladet.se</a>
    </div>
    <div class="processlinks-section-item-title">
        <a href="http://Cteabagz.com">Cteabagz.com</a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
[data-letter] {
margin:7px;
background:#ef8;
}
[data-letter]:before {
content:attr(data-letter);
font-size:36px;
margin:7px;
}
.processlinks-section-template
{
 width: 270px;
 height: 100%;
}
}
.processlinks-section-item-title
{
margin-top:5px;
}
.processlinks-section-item-title a
{
color:black;
}
.processlinks-section-item-title a:visited
{
color:black;
}
.processlinks-section-item-title a:hover
{
color:#0084c9;
}
```

Any kind of help is appreciated

Note: I have a javascript that appends stuff so I rather just stay with these two selectors.

If there is one item it seems to ruin the design and I think thats the problem.

Take a look: [jsbin.com/UHiZUJU/9/edit](http://jsbin.com/UHiZUJU/9/edit)

Answer (score 2):

Float both the letter and link to left and add clearfix with it.

[Updated jsfiddle](http://jsbin.com/UHiZUJU/6/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 1):

Add `float: left` to the `:before` psuedo-element that contains the letter, and `clear: left` to the section container:

```
[data-letter]:before {
  content:attr(data-letter);
  font-size:36px;
  margin:7px;
  display:inline-block;
}
.processlinks-section-item {
  clear:left;
}
```

[**Updated JSBin**](http://jsbin.com/UHiZUJU/7/)

Currently your `:before` psuedo-element is `display: block` by default in the absence of another `display` declaration, which means it automatically fills 100% the width of its parent and functions like it has a line break after it (as compared to `inline` elements).

Floating a `block` element means it only fills the width it needs rather than its usual behavior of filling the full width and also removes the implicit presence of a line break.  The `clear: left` on the container just ensures the float is reset for each section.

Comment: Thanks for a great explanation! Problem is if there is 1 item the design gets messed up take a look: http://jsbin.com/UHiZUJU/9/edit. Also it can be everything from 1-8 items inside each section. I think that cause you see on my link is why I couldnt achieve the design

Comment: In the event the content is shorter than the psuedo-element like that, you need to add a clearfix to the container.  Add `overflow: hidden` to the `.processlinks-section-item` container class: [Updated JSBin](http://jsbin.com/UHiZUJU/16/)

Comment: If you want you can also add an explicit width to the `:before` psuedo element to ensure it looks tidy / even when the leading letters/characters are not the same width.  There are also many other methods of the "clearfix" trick but `overflow: hidden` is the most simple in this context.

Comment: @Rohander If this answer helped you please take a second to mark it as the accepted answer :)

Comment: Do you have any idea how I can make sure that the space between the big letter and the text item is same on every item and big letter? Check the picture you will understand what i mean :)

Comment: @Rohander like I said, add a fixed width to the `:after` psuedoelement with the letter in it, then add a `margin-right` to it as well.

Comment: that would be assuming you want the links aligned horizontally - otherwise just add `margin-right` to the `:after` CSS and let the width remain auto

Comment: I fixed that issue but not I run in another one when I add a 3rd item this is what happens check the jsbin http://jsbin.com/UHiZUJU/20/edit

Answer (score 0):

To make it like in your image change your margin:auto 7px;